# For loop with nested Firebase queries Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node with the users list and a second node with the rating information for each user.
I would like to loop within the users of the first node and for each one get the rating from the second node. The problem is that the loop doesn't wait for the second node to give the answer, therefore the array returned is always empty.
I know I need to use await/async method but it's not working.
Thanks for help

```
return admin.database().ref('/user').once('value').then(async(snap) => {
for(const userId of snap) {
    admin.database().ref('/rating/' + userId.key).once('value').then(await (snap) =>{
        var rating = snap.val();
        array.push([userId.key, rating]);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("failed 1 " + error.code);
    });
}
return array;
}).catch(error => {
console.log("failed 2 " + error.code);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows (untested):

```
  const array = [];
  const userIds = [];
  return admin
    .database()
    .ref('/user')
    .once('value')
    .then((snap1) => {
      const promises = [];
      snap1.forEach((childSnapshot1) => {
        promises.push(
          admin
            .database()
            .ref('/rating/' + childSnapshot1.key)
            .once('value')
        );
        userIds.push(childSnapshot1.key);
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then((snap2) => {
      snap2.forEach((childSnapshot2, idx) => {
        const rating = childSnapshot2.val();
        array.push([userIds[idx], rating]);
      });
      return array;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //...
    });
```

---

As explained in the `Promise.all()` doc, "returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order". So for the `userIds` and `snap2` arrays, their elements orders are corresponding: you can therefore do `array.push([userIds[idx], rating]);`

Comment: thanks that worked! would it be possible to achieve the same result with async/await?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, but using `async/await` and `forEach` is not straightforward, see https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404.